# Why is $\int_{1/\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{M - 1} dt \leq C\int_{1/\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-t/2} dt?$

Tags: integration

> I am trying to figure out why $\int_{1/\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{M - 1} dt \leq C\int_{1/\epsilon}^{\infty} e^{-t/2} dt$ for $M > 0.$

Would it be because $Ce^{t/2}$ dominates $t^{M - 1}$ for large $t$ and some constant $C?$

Comment: Hint: Find $t_M$ finite such that, for every $t\geqslant t_M$, $$e^{-t}t^{M-1}\leqslant e^{-t/2}$$ and consider your integrals for every $$\epsilon\leqslant1/t_M$$